# Highcharts - show markers on zoom event (selection) and hide on reset zoom. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I hope you can shed some light on this.

Here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/uBhu7/

I've managed to show the markers on zoom (selection) event with this:

```
 events: {
        selection: function(event) {
            this.series[0].options.marker.enabled = true;
        },
```

Now the problem: is there a way to hide the markers when a user hits "reset zoom" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/uBhu7/1/

Basically, you need to destroy all markers when the selection is reset, then set the enabled option back to false so that the drawMarkers method doesn't create new ones.